# Okhttp and retrofit are not working together

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp

I am using following libs

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

The problem is retrofit is not getting along with okhttp. Even they are from squareup what is going on?

My application crashes as soon as it starts. How can i make both work?

```
Process: com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit, PID: 4748
03-13 03:08:37.471 4748-4748/com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.Endpoints
03-13 03:08:37.471 4748-4748/com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder.setEndpoint(RestAdapter.java:565)
03-13 03:08:37.471 4748-4748/com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit.api.ApiManager.<init>(ApiManager.java:171)
03-13 03:08:37.471 4748-4748/com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:27)
03-13 03:08:37.471 4748-4748/com.neberox.app.cloudbuckit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
```

Comment: try  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'

Comment: How does it crash?

Comment: @JesseWilson check the crash log

Comment: @GovindaP same thing. check the crash log

Comment: Have you define end point?

Comment: @BhavinShah it happens only if i add okhttp in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [link](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). If you are using **OKHttp** so you have to add [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio) too.

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'    //compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'   same error mate